# What was the downtime for?

Tags: support, downtime

Around an hour or so ago, SFF went into read-only mode. Apparently, it wasn't the only one - Stack Overflow and Super User went down as well, and I assume that all 153 sites experienced the same.

There was no warning on [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net), and [@StackStatus](http://twitter.com/stackstatus) didn't post anything. What was the downtime for?

As @CreationEdge said...:

> People are mostly poking fun here, but it could be a teaching moment to explain why the site goes down for small periods of time every now and then, when not "scheduled" (to our knowledge). Not every user is going to understand the dynamics of how a major website functions.

Comment: My feet got a bit cold, so I used the servers to warm them.

Comment: I noticed this too. No sooner had the panic attack started, than it came back online.

Comment: @Mithrandir StackOverflow. But seriously, it was <1 minute as far as I could tell.

Comment: Once every 3.2 years they have to move all the ones and zeroes, clean out from underneath them, and put them back.

Comment: Tim Post lost his keys again, so the unicorn dust used to power SE was locked away

Comment: Stackstatus shows nothing: https://twitter.com/StackStatus and https://www.stackstatus.net/

Comment: @AdamDavis Didn't I say that in the question?

Comment: @Adam of course it's not, it won't show down times of few minutes. No site has 100% uptime, not a single one in the world.

Comment: @Mithrandir Yes, you did.

Comment: [su]  went read only as well.

Comment: @David all sites were read only as far as I could see. Checked 5, all read only, so assumed all were

Comment: A STACKEXCHANGE SITE WENT DOWN FOR A MINUTE! QUICK, TO META TO ASK ABOUT IT!!!!

Comment: @Won't exactly. But it was *all* of them.

Comment: People are mostly poking fun here, but it could be a teaching moment to explain why the site goes down for small periods of time every now and then, when not "scheduled" (to our knowledge). Not every user is going to understand the dynamics of how a major website functions.